# Compiler error when subtracting std::strings

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++ so I'm just messing around with some stuff while reading articles and books. But I spent 20 minutes re-reading this over and over again and I can't tell what's wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    cout << "Hello there, this is your personal simple calculator.";
    cin.get();
    cout << "Type in what you want to do. (Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division)"<< endl;
    string c;
    getline (cin, c);

    if (c == "Addition")
    {
        string a_1;
        string a_2;
        cout << "You chose addition. Press enter" << endl ;
        cin.get();
        cout << "Type in the first value: ";
        getline( cin, a_1);
        cout << "Type in the second value: ";
        getline (cin, a_2);
        cout << a_1 << " + " << a_2 << " = " << a_1 + a_2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You spelled it wrong.";
        return 0;
    }
    if ( c == "Subtraction")
    {
        string s_1;
        string s_2;
        cout << "You chose subtraction. Press enter" << endl ;
        cin.get();
        cout << "Type in the first value: ";
        getline (cin, s_1);
        cout << "Type in the second value: ";
        getline (cin, s_2);
        cout << s_1 << " - " << s_2 << " = " << s_1 - s_2 << endl;
    }

}
```

I get this as the only error

> 42    83  C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Lesson - Header Files\LH1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator-' in 'first_argument - second_argument'

I don't get it. The addition sign works and everything but the subtraction works.
So I messed around with something else

```
cout << first_argument << " - " << second_argument << " = " << first_argument - second_argument << endl;
```

But that subtraction part works fine. I don't get it. Help please

Comment: Please think of a more descriptive title. This title could apply to thousands of questions.

Comment: `std::string` has no `operator-`.

Comment: The `+` operator for `std::string` does concatenation. There is no `operator-` and I don't know what you think it should do.

Comment: What would you expect the subtraction of two strings to result in?  A replace of string1 by string2 with ""?

Comment: Take a look at the output of your 'addition'.  You should notice that it did not perform arithmetic, but rather the concatenation of the two input strings.  In a similar manner, the subtraction of two strings will not do arithmetic, and you have not added a subtract operator to a derived subclass of strings, so the compiler is simply letting you know it does not know how to subtract two strings.

Comment: Convert the contents of the string to a number, then perform arithmetic on the number.

Answer (score 3):

`string` can deal with text. When you add two strings, they are concatenated (`"2"+"2"=="22"`, not `"4"`). String doesn't have `operator-`.

To deal with floating-point numbers, use `double`. To deal with integers, use `int`:

```
double d1, d2;
//some output
cin  >> d1;
//some output
cin  >> d2;
cout << d1 << " - " << d2 << " = " << (d1-d2) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

The addition part works because string + string results in stringstring. It appends the two strings and returns a new string.

But subtracting two strings doesn't mean anything.

What I believe you actually want to do is convert the strings into numbers and then subtract the numbers.

To do that, you need to use something like the following:

```
double val_1, val_2;
cin >> val_1;
cin >> val_2;

cout << "result is " << (val_1 - val_2) << endl;
```

I put the subtraction inside parenthesis because I believe the `<<` aka "shift" operator is on the same level as multiplication, which means that without them it would try to evaluate ("result is " << val_1) - (val_2 << endl).

Since I am not sure on operator precedence I checked http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and found that << is lower than subtraction, so my parenthesis weren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Hello there, this is your personal simple calculator.";
    cin.get();
    cout << "Type in what you want to do. (Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division)" << endl;
    string c;
    getline(cin, c);

    if (c == "Addition")
    {
        int a_1;
        int a_2;
        cout << "You chose addition. Press enter" << endl;
        cin.get();
        cout << "Type in the first value: ";
        cin >> a_1;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Type in the second value: ";
        cin >> a_2;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << a_1 << " + " << a_2 << " = " << a_1 + a_2 << endl;
    }

    else if (c == "Subtraction")
    {
        int s_1;
        int s_2;
        cout << "You chose subtraction. Press enter" << endl;
        cin.get();
        cout << "Type in the first value: ";
        cin >> s_1;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Type in the second value: ";
        cin >> s_2;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << s_1 << " - " << s_2 << " = " << s_1 - s_2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You spelled it wrong.";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use if else statements because otherwise your code won't have a chance to check to see if the user is trying to Subtract. It is best to leave the else at the very end.
Also changed the strings to ints because strings cannot subtract as they are not numbers.
On a final note, I used the cin.clear() & cin.ignore() to flush the cin buffer.